# Изменить пароль, который был задан при создании контейнера из образа

Tags: docker, auth, webdav

Я делал с такими параметрами:

```
docker run --restart always -v /srv/dav:/var/lib/dav \
    -e AUTH_TYPE=Basic -e USERNAME=webdav -e PASSWORD=******* \
    -e SSL_CERT=selfsigned --publish 443:443 -d k3vmcd/webdav
```

Как изменить пароль в работающем контейнере?

```
-e AUTH_TYPE=Basic -e USERNAME=webdav -e PASSWORD=******* \
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот контейнер [k3vmcd/webdav](https://hub.docker.com/r/k3vmcd/webdav) основан на Apache HTTPD. Поэтому точно такие же механизмы.

Внутри контейнера есть файл `/user.passwd` в которой ранится пароль в хешированом виде. Можно либо зайти через консоль в контейнер (`docker exec -it mycontainer sh`) и поменять его. Для генерации хеша используется команда

```
htpasswd -B -b -c "/user.passwd" $USERNAME $PASSWORD
```

Способ проще: создать этот файл с помощью [онлайн генератора](https://wtools.io/ru/generate-htpasswd-online) и подмонтировать его через volume.

Comment: если уж решили написать ответ, то сделайте его хоть капельку полезным. хотя приведя ссылку на [соответствующую команду](https://github.com/k3vmcd/docker-webdav/blob/261f75f521aa358dc5dc90fa9c020f21a9759caa/2.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L61).

Comment: спс, добавил больше деталей